# Conflict between swfobject and swffit

Tags: swfobject

- swfobject.js - among other things - detects whether the browser has the flash plugin, and if it does not, displays an error message (e.g. click here to get the flash plugin).
- swffit.js allows you to set minimum and maximum size for your swfs, so they shrink for small screens and enlarge for big screens (and, miraculously, it centers the swf X and Y).

The swffit download examples run swfobject.js first, then swffit.js.
This causes the following...

- In FF and Chrome with flash plugin enabled, swffit does its job
- In FF and Chrome with flash plugin disabled, there is no swf, but also no error message, just a blank screen - somehow swffit overrides swfobject's very useful function.

Reversing the order, i,e. swffit.js first, then swfobject.js...

- In FF and Chrome, with flash plugin enabled or disabled, I get no swf but there is the error message.

In summary, I need the  swffit's resizability, but also swfobject's error message, but it looks like you can't have both together with these two scripts. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, I found it was a placement problem, not a script conflict.
If you disable your flash plugin and try the Example Pages (bottom of page) here:

- http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/

The Basic example (1) shows the swfobject error message, 
but the Example Page With Maximum Size - Centered (4) does not.

Playing with css on a local file, it turned out the message was there (in 4) but off the screen top left. If you look at (3) Example Page With Maximum Size - Centered Horizontally you can see the problem.

The fix was - in the case of swffit.fit("my_flash",550,289,800,436):

```
<div id="my_flash" style="position:relative;">
<div style="width:550px;height:289px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:120px;text-align:center;margin-top:100px">
error message here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

That centers the error message at max width (800px) and minwidth (550px).

Answer (score 0):

Easy, only invoke SWFFit if the SWFObject embed was successful. Do this using SWFObject's [callback method](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/the-callback-function/).

You didn't provide any code examples, so I'll use one from the SWFFit site:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("example.swf", "my_flash", "550", "400", "8.0.0");
swffit.fit("my_flash");
```

Example reconfigured to use SWFObject's callback method:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var callbackHandler = function (e){
    if(e.success){
        swffit.fit("my_flash");
    }
};

swfobject.embedSWF("example.swf", "my_flash", "550", "400", "8.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes, callbackHandler);
```